# How in PhpStrom clicking on Interface method to open service method implemention?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have Interface defined in file app/Library/Services/ActionsHistoryServiceInterface.php :

```
interface ActionsHistoryServiceInterface
{
    public static function addLog(Model $model, string $action_type, string $body, callable $func = null, $table = null, $id = null);

    ...
    
}
```

and Service class in app/Library/Services/ActionsHistory.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Library\Services;

use App\Library\Services\ActionsHistoryServiceInterface;
...
class ActionsHistory implements ActionsHistoryServiceInterface
{
    public static function addLog(
        Model $model,
        string $action_type,
        string $body,
        callable $func = null,
        $table = null,
        $id = null
    ) {
```

and I have binding class in app/Providers/ActionsHistoryServiceProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ActionsHistoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Library\Services\ActionsHistoryServiceInterface', 'App\Library\Services\ActionsHistory');
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

this way is good as in method register above I can bind another implementaion of ActionsHistory
(say different for dev/production mode or Permissions of logged user).

The question is that with PhpStorm 2021 calling in controller on line :

```
    $actionsHistory = \App::make(App\Library\Services\ActionsHistoryServiceInterface::class);
    $actionsHistory->addLog(
        model: $modelInstance,
        action_type: 'action_type'
        body:
        ' User ' . $request->userId . '=>' . $user->name . ' (' . $user->email . ') was subscribed to subscription ' . $subscriptionId . '=>' . $subscription->title
    );
```

PhpStorm opens addLog method of ActionsHistoryServiceInterface, but not implementation
in app/Library/Services/ActionsHistory.php class...
Can I open implementation class when I click on it controller?
Maybe I need other definition of class/Interface in this case ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a [Go to Implementation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation) option available either via keyboard shortcuts ot the contextual menu.

Comment: I use [ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and with the command `php artisan ide-helper:meta` it generates a .phpstorm.meta.php file with the correct bindings. Even if it's not correct you can just modify it manually after it is created

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea